# Conditional Statement Returning False

Tags: java, logic, conditional-statements

Why does this statement return false? When I calculate it by hand I get 114 = 114 which should be true:

```
System.out.println(114 == (114.0 / Math.PI * Math.PI));
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%.15f\n", (114.0 / Math.PI * Math.PI));`.

Comment: When you calculated it by hand, how many bits after the binary point did you carry in the intermediate result `114.0/Math.PI`? What rounding rule did you use to produce those bits?

Answer (score 2):

That's because by using `Math.PI` you introduce floating point arithmetic, which is not as precise as actual integer arithmetic. The result of the right side will in fact 114.00000000000001, a value that is very very very close to 114, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code:

```
double res=114.0 / Math.PI * Math.PI;
System.out.println(res);
```

**Result is: 114.00000000000001 not 114.**

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
System.out.println(114.0 / Math.PI * Math.PI);
```

will print

```
114.00000000000001
```

You can try

```
System.out.println(114 == (int)(114.0 / Math.PI * Math.PI));
```

(converting the float to int)**This will return true**...